# Django integrity error NOT NULL constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i'm creating a blog site which requires a login to write a post.As of now, ive just created the create post and update post views, but when i try to submit a created post, this integrity error is raised. I dont know how to get through this. Help is appreciated :)
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Sjj.png)

*VIEWS*

```
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
form_class = forms.PostForm
template_name = "blog/create_post.html"
```

*APP URLS*

```
app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
path("login/",auth_view.LoginView.as_view(template_name="blog/login.html"), name='login'),
path("logout/",auth_view.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
path("signup/",views.SignUpView.as_view(), name="signup"),
path("new/",views.CreatePost.as_view(), name="newpost")
]
```

*ROOT URLS*

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name = "home"),
path('logged/',views.LoggedPage.as_view(), name='logged'),
path('thanks',views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name='thanks'),
path('blog/',include("blog.urls", namespace='blog')),
path('blog/',include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

Comment: please write your code here instead of code picture.

Comment: Don't add code in images. Use ``` Your Code ```

Comment: Please include *code*, not images of code: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your `CreatePost`, you should attach the logged in user to the post:

```
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = forms.PostForm
    template_name = 'blog/create_post.html'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

You should also specify a [**`success_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url), or a [**`get_success_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) to specify to what view you redirect in case of a succesful POST request. You can also implement the [**`get_absolute_url`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url), to redirect to the details of that `Post` object.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `CreatePostView`, instead of <s>`CreatePost`</s>.